# How to add a title on the center-left of the plot in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

As a very late contribution to `TidyTuesday` challenge of Bob Ross's Paintings, I have tried to plot 10 paintings of Bob Ross. Without further background, here is my code;

```
library(tidyverse)
library(showtext)
library(showtextdb)
library(ggthemes)
library(ggtext)
library(magick)
library(ggimage)
library(cropcircles)
library(cowplot)
library(patchwork)


font_add_google("Lora", bold.wt = 700, family = "plottitle")
font_add_google("Roboto Slab", family = "title") 
font_add_google("Ubuntu", family = "caption")

font_add('fa-reg', 'fonts/Font Awesome 6 Free-Regular-400.otf')
font_add('fa-brands', 'fonts/Font Awesome 6 Brands-Regular-400.otf')
font_add('fa-solid', 'fonts/Font Awesome 6 Free-Solid-900.otf')
showtext_auto()

bob_ross <- readr::read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rfordatascience/tidytuesday/master/data/2023/2023-02-21/bob_ross.csv')
bob_ross_top <- bob_ross %>%
  mutate(col_num_n = str_count(colors, ",") + 1) %>%
  arrange(desc(col_num_n)) %>%
  slice(1:10) %>%
  mutate(image = map(img_src, image_read),
         img_circle = circle_crop(img_src, border_size = 12, border_colour = "white"),
         painting_title = gsub(" ", "<br>", painting_title),
         painting_title = case_when(painting_title == "Lake<br>in<br>the<br>Valley" ~ "Lake<br>in the<br>Valley",
                                    painting_title == "Waterfall<br>in<br>the<br>Woods" ~ "Waterfall<br>in the<br>Woods",
                                    .default = as.character(painting_title)))


plot <- ggplot() +
  geom_image(data = bob_ross_top, aes(x = 1, y = 1, image = img_circle), size = 0.8) +
  scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0, 0)) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) +
  labs(caption = "") +
  theme_void() +
  facet_wrap(~painting_title, ncol = 4, strip.position = "right") +
  theme(# axis.text = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major.y = element_blank(),
        strip.background = element_blank(),
        strip.text.y.right = element_markdown(hjust = 0, angle = 0, size = 60, family = "title", face = "bold", lineheight = 0.1),
        panel.spacing.y = unit(1, "cm"),
        panel.spacing.x = unit(0.5, "cm"),
        plot.background = element_rect(fill = "cornsilk", color = "cornsilk"),
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = "cornsilk", color = "cornsilk"),
        plot.caption = element_markdown(linewidth = 0.02, hjust = 0.5, size = 45, family = "caption"))


title_plot <- ggplot() +
  geom_text(aes(x = 2, y = 25, label = "Bob Ross\nPainting"), 
            size = 60, family = "plottitle", fontface = "bold", color = "black", lineheight = 0.1) +
  geom_text(aes(x = 0, y = 20, label = "This plot demonstrates\n10 most colorful\npaintings in Bob\nRoss's show."), 
            size = 30, family = "title", color = "black", lineheight = 0.1) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 12)) +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 12)) +
  theme_void() +
  theme(plot.background = element_rect(fill = "cornsilk", color = "cornsilk"),
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = "cornsilk", color = "cornsilk"),
        panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major.y = element_blank(),
        # axis.text = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank())

final_plot <- title_plot +
  plot +
  plot_layout(widths = c(1, 5)) +
  theme(plot.background = element_rect(fill = "cornsilk", color = "cornsilk"),
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = "cornsilk", color = "cornsilk"))

ggsave("~/plot.png", dpi = 720,  height = 6, width = 12)
```

The resulting plot is something like that;

[image]

Now, what I am suffering to achieve for the last couple of days is adding a title and subtitle to the plot but they should be placed on the left-center of the plot. I could not find an easy way to make it happen using `theme()` function's properties, and therefore I had to go for making another plot including the title and subtitle and merging them using `patchwork` package. In that case, let me ask the following three questions;

1. Is there any any to place the title and subtitle on the left-center of the plot without making a new plot? Additionally, it would be very helpful to know if I can customize their positions further such as setting the title's coordinate to c(0, 0.7) and subtitle's coordinate to c(0, 0.3) and etc.
2. If not, how can I align the title centered while subtitle left-center? (As both title and subtitle are in the same-separate plot, when I align them differently, their positions are crashed (you can experience it with setting `hjust` to 0 and 0.5 for title and subtitle in `title_plot` respectively.)
3. Why there is a white border around the plot, although I set `panel.background` and `plot.background` to cornsilk in each and every time?

Thank you for your kind attention beforehand.

Answer (score 3):

One option to avoid creating your titles as a second plot would be to add it as an axis title as in the approach by @r2evans and use `ggtext::element_markdown` which allows to have different fonts, font sizes, ... . However, this option still does not allow to position the "title" and "subtitle" separately.

Note: The issue with the white border is due to the theme applied for the patch as a whole when using `patchwork` which you can set via `plot_annotation(theme = ...)`.

```
axis_title <- paste(
  "<span style='font-family: plottitle; font-size: 60mm'>**Bob Ross<br>Painting**</span>",
  "<span style='font-family: title; font-size: 30mm'>This plot demonstrates<br>10 most colorful<br>paintings in Bob<br>Ross's show.</span>",
  sep = "<br><br>"
)

plot + 
  labs(y = axis_title) +
  theme(
    axis.title.y = ggtext::element_markdown(lineheight = 1)
  )
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A (somewhat fragile) hack, perhaps, but something like this?

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, disp)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_y_continuous(
    name = expression(
      atop(bold("Bob Ross Painting\n\n"),
           scriptstyle("This plot demonstrates\n10 most colorful\npaintings in Bob\nRoss's show."))
    )) +
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(angle = 0, vjust = 0.5))
```

[image: axis title as title/subtitle]

The extra `\n\n` on the first string is because the second longer string wrapping takes a bit more space. (It's this "hack" that makes me call this a hack, perhaps a little fragile.) Also, I'm not entirely sure with this how to center-justify the text ... `hjust=0.5` doesn't do it.